# Access Birt Cell

Tags: java, birt

I'm having a trouble in accessing a Birt Cell value from another cell.

Cell #1 has dynamic text with it's expression. It's binded to a DataSet#1.
Cell #2 has dynamic text with it's expression. It's binded to a DataSet#2.

Cell #3 must use cell1 and cell2, and count an expression based on their value. Let's say cell#1.value()+cell#2.value()

The thing is, I can't find a way to get cell#1 value.
I've tried:

```
this.setDisplayValue(reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(997).text());
```

But got an error on processing

```
Cannot find function text in object org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.TextDataHandle@edc8ca
```

It also didn't have functions like getValue, getDisplayValue

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Is there some reason my answer below is not working for you?

Comment: @James Jenkins , well i couldn't bind my output to a binding, becauseit schould be a result of combination of different datasets. And I couldn't change my sql. So I used scriptinfg. When sells were counted, they put their result into a variable, onrendering the last cell aggregated the variables.

Comment: Just copy your code from the 'dynamic text' and paste it in to a new 'Data' item.  Then it will be available for binding.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of information here on your report design. But making a couple of educated guesses.  Dynamic text is not the best choice for doing anything with the results afterwords. Two easier paths to solutions are -

1 - If practical join your data sources into one data source with computed columns for your values in cell 1, 2 & 3

- In the Outline, right mouse click 'Data Sets' and select 'New Joint Data Set'

2 - Use a 'Data' item for cells 1 & 2, this will allow you use the 'Aggregation' item to sum (*or otherwise work with*) the values in the 'Data' item

- In the palette of report items with 'Dynamic Text'